# Unmarshaling a SOAP response in Go

Tags: go, soap, unmarshalling

I am making a SOAP call to an API, Here is a sample response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <soapenv:envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:body>
      <soapenv:fault>
        <faultcode>
          ERR109
        </faultcode>
        <faultstring>
          Account Expired. Result code is 2163
        </faultstring>
        <detail>
          <ns1:serviceexception xmlns:ns1="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/common/v2_1">
            <messageid>
              ERR109
            </messageid>
            <text>
              Account Expired. Result code is 2163
            </text>
            <variables>
              2163
            </variables>
          </ns1:serviceexception>
        </detail>
      </soapenv:fault>
    </soapenv:body>
  </soapenv:envelope>
```

To unmarshal this response, I have built some structs:

```
type SoapResponse struct {
    Body    ResponseBody `soapenv:"body"`
}
type ResponseBody struct {
    Fault   Fault    `soapenv:"fault"`
}
type Fault struct {
    FaultCode   string `xml:"faultcode"`
    FaultString string `xml:"faultstring"`
    Detail      Detail `xml:"detail"`
}
type Detail struct {
    ServiceException ServiceException `ns1:"serviceexception"`
}
type ServiceException struct {
    ID          string `xml:"messageid"` 
    MessageText string `xml:"text"`
    ErrorCode   string `xml:"variables"`
}
```

And here is the code that does the unmarshaling part:

```
responseBody, _:= ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
var soapResponse = new(SoapResponse)
err := xml.Unmarshal(responseBody, soapResponse)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Error!")
    }
```

The problem is that all `soapResponse` properties are populated just right, except for `soapResponse.Body.Fault.Detail.ServiceException.ID` which prints nothing.
I couldn't figure out why. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try changing all your tag names to `xml`? (https://play.golang.org/p/H4CA7DqVni)

Comment: @mkopriva I did as you suggested, It kinda of worked.
When I changed all tag names to xml, I could no longer unmarshal the response, but I could fully unmarshal the `data` variable in your sample.
First question is that why did this happen? 
The second is what's the difference between `data` variable in your sample and `ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)`? I couldn't figure out just yet.

Comment: are you 100% sure that the sample response that you provided has the same structure as the content of `responseBody`?

Comment: Good question. I was checking that right now. The ONLY difference is in some tags capitalization. `fault` is `Fault`,`serviceexception` is `ServiceException` and `messageid` is `messageId` . After changing all these tags to exactly match the actual response, everything worked perfectly.
I still don't know why before changing capitalization everything still worked except for `messageId`? I would except it to either be case sensitive or not. Strange.

Comment: `messageId` didn't work because it's lower case and doesn't match the actual field name, whereas `Fault` and `ServiceException` match the field names exactly, Go's unmarshaler, xml and json as well, does that, if it can't find a tag match, it tries fiel name match.

Comment: @mkopriva I guess I couldn't explain it well on my previous comment,
The `fault` xml tag in the struct, is `Fault` in the response, and again, `serviceexception` in the struct is `ServiceException` in the actual response. same goes for `messageid ` and `messageId`. I wonder why Go's unmarshaler didn't really care about the name mismatch between all tags in the structs and the actual response, except for `messageid`? The sample in the question was working despite the mismatch between `fault` and `serviceexception` in the structs and their respective CamelCase name in the actual response.

Comment: I think I understood you well and my answer explains that correctly. If you have xml like this `<body><Fault>sdfdsf</Fault></body>` and struct like this `type Body struct { Fault string `soapenv:"fault" }` then Unmarshal will match because the name of the field and the name of the elements match, if you change the tag from `soapenv` to `xml` Unmarshal will not work because the tag value does not match the elemnt.

Comment: Basically you were using incorrect tag names so Unmarshal was matching against the field's name instead. The Field `Fault` matches the element `<Fault>...` and the Field `ServiceException` matches the element `<ServiceException>...` And where you were using correct tag names you were using incorrect tag values, the element `<messageId>...` does not match the tag value `messageid`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156049/discussion-between-sam-and-mkopriva).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may parse got XML with such structures:

```
type SoapResponse struct {
    Body ResponseBody `xml:"soapenv body"`
}
type ResponseBody struct {
    Fault Fault `xml:"fault"`
}
type Fault struct {
    FaultCode   string `xml:"faultcode"`
    FaultString string `xml:"faultstring"`
    Detail      Detail `xml:"detail"`
}
type Detail struct {
    ServiceException ServiceException `xml:"serviceexception"`
}
type ServiceException struct {
    ID          string `xml:"messageid"`
    MessageText string `xml:"text"`
    ErrorCode   string `xml:"variables"`
}
```

I've added namespace for the first element and fixed some definitions. Working example - https://play.golang.org/p/vZQhaxYikX